# Firebase trouble with auth.verifyIdToken

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm building a react-native app and right now i am trying to display my user's name using my stored JWT so it looks like this in my code :

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import firebase from '../../firebase';
import { auth } from '../../firebase'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { globalStyles } from '../../styles/global'



const SearchScreen = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    

    // Get the current user's ID token
    const getCurrentUser = async (key) => {
      const idToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
      // Decode the ID token to get user information
      const decodedToken = await auth.verifyIdToken(idToken);
      console.log("here is the decoded one :",decodedToken)
      // Set the user's information to the state
      setUser(decodedToken);
    };

    getCurrentUser('jwt');
```

I did setup my firebase in a "firebase.js" file in my root directory :

```js
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat';

const firebaseConfig = {
// private infos & shit you know
};


let app;
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
    app = firebase.app()
}


const auth = getAuth();

export { auth };
```

So here i am trying to figure why i get this error :

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish, but the idea of decoding an auth token doesn't really make sense for frontend app code.  It's a backend thing.  Whatever you're trying to do, you're probably not going about it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

`verifyIdToken` is not a method provided by the React Native library for Firebase Authentication.  You can see in the [API documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth) it's not listed anywhere.

The ability to verify an ID token is reserved only for Firebase Admin backend SDKs with code that needs to validate the user invoking the code.  You can read documentation about that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).  Firebase Admin does not work on frontend apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Firebase REST API to validate your ID token.
Take a look in [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth?hl=pt-br#section-get-account-info) section of API documentation

PS: this will only validate firebase's ID token. If you're using custom JWT Tokens this will not work

Comment: This isn't a good idea because it requires admin credentials to use that API, and you never want to expose those credentials to frontend code.  That's a huge security hole, because someone could easily intercept those credentials and do some serious damage to the project. All that should be kept secret on a backend you control.